# Optimize combination of cards to least multicolored cards

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, combinations, integer-programming

I asked a question about [how to calculate a combination of specific color pair cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639773/find-required-card-combination-to-add-up-to-a-specific-number-of-colors). I'd now like to optimize the calculation in a way, that the least number of triple and double colored cards are used but the criteria are still met. How would I do that?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're using thee colors now, you want to specify the total number of cards and the total number of each color, and minimize the number of multi-color cards.  Is that correct?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes right. Ideally I would like to minimize the triple colored cards first and after that minimize the double colored ones.

Comment: I added the `integer-programming` tag in hopes of attracting the attention of someone who knows more about this than I do.  see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the required number of cards.
Let $A$ be the required number of cards of color $1$.
Let $B$ be the required number of cards of color $2$.
Let $C$ be the required number of cards of color $3$.
Let $n_i$ be the number of single-color cards of color $i$, $i=1,2,3$.
Let $n_{ij}$ be the number of two-color cards of colors $i$, and $j$, $1\leq i<j\leq3$.
Let $n_{123}$ be the number of three-color cards.

Then the problem is:

Minimize $$n_{12}+n_{13}+n_{23}+n_{123}\tag1$$
subject to
$$
\begin{align}
N&= n_1+n_2+n_3+n_{12}+n_{13}+n_{23}+n_{123}\\
A &= n_1+n_{12}+n_{13}+n_{123}\\
B&=n_2+n_{12}+n_{23}+n_{123}\\
C &= n_3+n_{13}+n_{23}+n_{123}
\end{align}
$$
where all the variables are non-negative integers.

This is an integer linear programming (ILP) problem, and hand solution would probably be arduous.  I looked for an online solver, but didn't find one.  I did find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHdgGCazfkg) which apparently explains how to use the ILP solver in Excel, if you have that available.

The way $(1)$ is set up, the total number of multi-color cards is minimized.  If you especially want to reduce the number of three color cards, you can add a weight in the objective function.  Instead of minimizing $(1)$, minimize
$$n_{12}+n_{13}+n_{23}+2n_{123}\tag{1'}$$
You might want to experiment with some other weights.

**EDIT**

I don't have Excel, but it turns out that Libre Office Calc also has a linear programming solver.  Unfortunately, it requires a java runtime, and I don't have one installed.  Libre Office is free.

**EDIT**

Here's a thought.  I'll give an example to show what I have in mind.
Suppose $$\begin{align}
N&=24\\
A&=17\\
B&=17\\
C&=19
\end{align}$$
First imagine that we have $17$ cards of color $1$, $17$ of color $2$, and $19$ of color $3$.  That's $54$ cards, $29$ more than we're allowed.  Can we satisfy the requirements without using three-color cards?  Every time we replace two single-color cards by a two-color card, we have a net reduction of $1$ card.  To reduce the number of cards by $29$ using only two-color cards would take $29$ two-color cards, and that's already more cards than we're allowed, so we must use three-color cards.

What's the smallest number of three-color cards we can use?  If we use $t$ of them, we get a new problem, with 
$$\begin{align}
N'&=N-t\\
A'&=A-t\\
B'&=B-t\\
C'&=C-t
\end{align}$$
If we are to solve this without using any more three-color cards, we must have$$A'+B'+C'\leq N'$$ which results in $$t\geq\frac{A+B+C-N}2$$  In this problem we have $t\geq10$.  If we use $10$ three-color cards, we have
$$\begin{align}
N'&=14\\
A'&=7\\
B'&=7\\
C'&=9
\end{align}$$
and since $A'+B'+C'-N'=9$ we must use $9$ two-color cards.  There are many ways to do this.  We could, for example, use $4$ cards with colors $1$ and $3$ and $5$ cards with colors $2$ and $3$.  Then we'd also have $3$ monotone cards in color $1$, $2$ in color $2$ and $0$ in color $3$.

Comment: God dammit, that's way more complicated than I thought. Need to wrap my head arount this somehow, thanks for the contribution!

Comment: Do you have a specific problem in mind?  Or do you need to do a bunch of these with differing values of $A,B,C,N$?  This is a very special case.  All the constraints are equalities, and all the coefficients are $0! and $1$.  maybe there's an easier way.  I'll think about it.

Comment: I'd like to have a formula (or however you want to call it, I can't think of a better word off of the top of my head right now) which is applicable with various numbers for A, B, C and N that gives me the ideal number of all the small n

Comment: Found an online solver, though I think I'm using it wrong, because it always states the problem has no solution. Maybe you want to try it http://www.phpsimplex.com/simplex/simplex.htm?l=es

Comment: @DrDecane You'll have to give me the values of $N,A,B,C$  No wait.  the tool you found is for linear programming, but not for *integer* linear programming.  It would give solutions with fractional cards.

Comment: Ah, that's to bad. My fault! The values of an example I came up with would be: N=24, A=B=17, C=19.

Comment: @DrDecane I can do that one.  I added the solution.

Comment: @DrDecane I think I have the algorithm.  I'm writing a python script to test it.  It may take some time.

Answer (score 0):

*If* double- and triple-color cards are equally costly, I think you can solve the problem without resorting to an integer program. Let $z=n_{12} + n_{13} + n_{23} + n_{123}$ be the quantity to be minimized.  Starting from the constraints in the answer from @saulspatz, we can observe that $$A + B + C - N = z + n_{123}.$$So you minimize $z$ by maximizing $n_{123}$, subject to balancing the four equations. For the example with $N=24, A=B=17, C=19$, we have $$A + B + C - N = 29 = n_{12} + n_{13} + n_{23} + 2n_{123}.\,\,(1)$$ So we set $n_{123}=14$ (the most it can be in (1)), leaving us with $N-n_{123}=10$ more cards to choose, of which $29-2(14)=1$ must be two-colored. "Net demands" are $A-n_{123}=17-14=3=B-n_{123}$ and $C-n_{123}=19-14=5$. We can complete the solution with any two-colored card and the requisite number of single color cards. (If any net demand were zero, that would rule out two of the two-color combinations.) I tested this with the solver in LibreOffice and it confirmed the solution.

Note that the solution will always involve exactly zero or one two-color card, depending on whether $A+B+C-N$ is odd or even. It depends on the assumption that three-color cards are no worse than two-color cards.

Comment: How do you come up with 14 triple colored cards when the goal is to minimize these first and we already established 10 to be the minimum in saulspatz's answer?

Comment: He uses 10 tri-colors and 9 bi-colors, for a total of 19 multicolored cards. My answer uses 14 tri-colors and one bi-color, for a total of 15. As I said, I'm working off the assumption that tri-colors are no worse than bi-colors, which is consistent with your phrasing: "the least number of triple and double colored cards". If you want to treat tri-colors as more expensive than bi-colors, my solution does not apply.